# Alterar a ordem de uma tag XML via T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Olá!

Estou com uma demanda onde por um determinado motivo, o XML foi gerado com a ordem das tags trocadas... :(

Cenário: Possuo uma coluna no banco de dados SQL Server (a partir da versão 2008) que contém XML de NF-e salva a partir de uma aplicação Windows. Estes XML, conforme falei anteriormente, foram inseridos com a ordem das tags incorretas. Devido ao número de registros incorretos já inseridos no banco de dados, pensei em criar um script que altere a ordem das tags conforme a seguir:

```
<tag>
   <tag2> Y </tag2>
   <tag1> Z </tag1>
</tag>
```

onde o correto seria:

```
<tag>
   <tag1> Z </tag1>
   <tag2> Y </tag2>
</tag>
```

Segue modelo parcial do XML, exatamente no ponto que preciso de auxílio (primeiro qrCode e depois urlChave).

```
<[...]>
   <infNFeSupl> 
      <urlChave>https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFCE/NFCE-COM.aspx</urlChave> 
      <qrCode><![CDATA[https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFCE/NFCE-COM.aspx?chNFe=43180803167598000104650010000003051845389930&nVersao=100&tpAmb=1&dhEmi=323031382d30382d30335430393a32363a33372d30333a3030&vNF=55.00&vICMS=0.00&digVal=6a467a6a633157556578702f30517536627a2f732f7271306933773d&cIdToken=000001&cHashQRCode=afc69d3001a635df776512e797ea3054d00054cf]]></qrCode>
    </infNFeSupl>
</[...]>
```

Eis minha dúvida: Como eu faria esta alteração?

Encontrei alguns exemplos de como modificar atributos do XML, mas não as tags em si. Aceito sugestões.

Desde já agradeço. :)

Comment: Qual a necessidade de inverter a ordem? Como há tags que identificam o conteúdo, a ordem não importa. Se no banco de dados ficou invertido, então me parece que a falha está no programa de importação...

Comment: Olá José, a API de terceiros no qual recebe este XML valida cada tag. Sendo absolutamente necessário esta alteração.